# Handling links and display paths in react

Tags: reactjs

As I understand it, in order for react to behave as expected we need to provide content to be displayed on a page as well as a way to navigate to the desired page.

This means we need to have the same path information in at least two places:

1. The app display
2. The navbar for changing the page.

I'm curious if there's a best practice for keeping this definition in one place yet having it accessible in multiple locations.

What I'm doing looks something like this:

App.js

```
const home = "/"
const away = "/away"

function App() {
   return {
       <Router>
          <Navbar home={home} away={away}/>
          <Switch>
             <Route exact path={home}>
                <Home/>
             </Route>
             <Route exact path = {away}>
                <Away/>
             </Route>
          </Switch>
       </Router>
              
          
   }
}
```

Navbar.js

```
  Navbar = ({home, away}) -> {
  
  return (
      <NavLink exact to={home}>Home</NavLink>
      <NavLink exact to={away}>Away</NavLink>
  )
}
```

This will get more cumbersome as time goes on so I'm wondering what the "standard" way is for doing this.

Comment: I don't know if a de-facto way to share the paths has really emerged, but you could just export the path as a variable from the module which contains that page's component, and import that variable in both App and Navbar.

Comment: I like that idea! So would you export the path as its own variable or would it be a member of, for example, Home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really a "standard" way for sharing the paths, but one way you could do this is by storing the path as a variable in the module containing the pages, and just export it and import the variable into both App and Navbar. For example:

```
// Home.jsx
export default function Home() { /* ... */ }
export const homePath = '/home';


// Away.jsx
export default function Away() { /* ... */ }
export const awayPath = '/away';


// App.jsx
import { Home, homePath } from './Home';
import { Away, awayPath } from './Away';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={homePath}>
          <Home />
        </Route>
        <Route exact path={awayPath}>
          <Away />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

// Navbar.jsx
import { homePath } from "./Home";
import { awayPath } from "./Away";

export default function Navbar({ home, away }) {
  return (
    <>
      <NavLink exact to={homePath}>
        Home
      </NavLink>
      <NavLink exact to={awayPath}>
        Away
      </NavLink>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: just as a head up, I think you need to replace the "default" with const for this to work